# How To Do This Bracket Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrices

I am a dummy trying to read as much as I can of  'Quantum Physics For Dummies'.

On page 35 they show a multiplication for <Ψ|R|Ψ> and I don't know how to do it. Can someone please tell me how or point me to where I can find out?

Comment: Maybe this will help, or at least give you some more words to refine your search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Linear_operators_acting_on_bras

Comment: It would improve your Question to spell out what $\Psi$ and $R$ are.  This would expedite Readers' responses based on whether it is something you already understand or something that will need to be researched and explained to you.

Answer (score 1):

A very short version (using matrices, per your tag).

First, let's talk about what a "ket" is.  Simply put, a "ket" (denoted $|B\rangle$) is a column vector.  So, we have that $$|B\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} B_1 \\ B_2 \\ \vdots \\ B_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, there's also Bras (denoted $\langle A|$ )- these are row vectors, so we have that $$\langle A| = \begin{pmatrix} A_1^* & A_2^* & \cdots & A_n^*\end{pmatrix}$$  Note that the entries of $\langle A|$ are the complex conjugates - this is important.

Conveniently, we have that combining a Bra and a Ket works kind of how you'd expect it:

\begin{align}
\langle A|B\rangle & = \langle A|\,|B\rangle \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} A_1^* & A_2^* & \cdots & A_n^*\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} B_1 \\ B_2 \\ \vdots \\ B_n\end{pmatrix}\\
&=A_1^*B_1+A_2^*B_2+\cdots +A_n^*B_n
\end{align}

In this way, evaluating a Braket (in a finite dimensional space) is the same as taking the dot product.

You might notice that $\langle A|$ was defined so its both the complex conjugate of $|A\rangle$, but also the transpose.  We have the identity $\langle A|^\dagger = |A\rangle$.

Finally, you posted asking about $\langle \Psi|R|\Psi\rangle$.  We already determined that $$\langle \Psi| = \begin{pmatrix} \Psi_1^* & \cdots & \Psi_n^*\end{pmatrix} $$ and $$|\Psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}\Psi_1 \\ \vdots \\ \Psi_n\end{pmatrix}$$, so what is $R$?  Here, $R$ is an operator (an $n\times n$ matrix), where $R$ takes a rov vector (ket) $|\Psi\rangle$ to another row vector, which we just call $R|\Psi\rangle$.  This is just done by matrix multiplication:

\begin{align}
R|\Psi\rangle & = \begin{pmatrix} R_{11} & \cdots & R_{1n} \\
\vdots &&\vdots \\
R_{n1} &\cdots & R_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \Psi_1 \\ \vdots \\ \Psi_n\end{pmatrix} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix} R_{11}\Psi_1+\cdots +R_{1n}\Psi_n \\
\vdots \\
R_{n1}\Psi_1 +\cdots+R_{nn}\Psi_n\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Despite the sum in this, this is just a column vector (so another ket).

So, $R|\Psi\rangle$ is a ket, so we can combine it with a bra $\langle \Psi|$ to get just a scalar in the end.

Anyway, there's plenty of other stuff about it, but that's a decent start.  Many properties from Braket notation are just matrix properties in disguise (as you saw with $\langle A|^\dagger = |A\rangle$).